# .SVN and determining relations of local files to their path in the repository?

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to determine the mapping of a local file to its absolute path in the repository. Ideally, I'm looking for the other way around actually. I have an API that provides to me the full path to a file in the repository remotely. I'd like to take that information and look somewhere local and find its local copy. I thought .svn folder would be where this information would live. However, when I'm looking in this file I see two folders pristine and tmp. Additionally, there are files entries,format, and wc.db. From my research I can tell that this is how the new SVN 1.7 stores its data. Instead of having .SVN folders in each directory it is instead just in the root. For the life of me I cannot find where to look to find that information.

The ultimate end goal is be able to quickly make API call to get a location remotely to a file. Then look somewhere locally to see where that file is mapped to locally. Then with an eclipse plugin I know where that local file lives and can in return open it for the user. Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

**Get revision and relative path:**

```
./sqlite3.exe wc.db  "select changed_revision, repos_path from NODES order by changed_revision desc limit 1" > xx.txt
```

**Get root path:**

```
./sqlite3.exe wc.db  "select root from REPOSITORY;"
```

hope this two will help.